# php shows empty array but ajax shows the data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use the data that AJAX sends in PHP but for some reason says that the array is empty I also don't get any errors from PHP or in my console. the console.log(data) shows the array with with the values of the selects. After the PHP there is HTML where the script.js is.[image: console.log]console.log

*index.php*

```
 <?php
    error_reporting(-1);
    $value1 = "";
    $value2 = "";
    print_r($_POST); 
    if (isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['date'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
            echo "Yes, mail is set";
            $value1 = $_POST['date'];
            $value2 = $_POST['quantity'];
        } else {
            echo "No, mail is not set";
        }
        exit;
    }
    echo $value1; 
    echo $value2;
    $canmakereservation = "https://www.planyo.com/rest/?method=can_make_reservation&api_key=YOURKEY&resource_id=110556&start_time=2018-04-25 09:00&end_time=2018-04-25 12:00&quantity=5";
    $cleancanmakereservation = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $canmakereservation);
    $reservationavailable = file_get_contents("$cleancanmakereservation");
    $reservationAvailable = json_decode($reservationavailable, true);
    // echo "$cleancanmakereservation";
    // var_dump($reservationAvailable);
 ?>
```

*script.js*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var date = "date";
var begin = "begin";
var eind = "eind";
var aantal = "aantal";


$('#datum').change(function() {
  date = $("#datum").val();
  console.log(date);
});
$('#beginTijd').change(function(){
    begin =( $(this).val() ); 
    console.log(begin);      
});
$('#Tijdsduur').change(function(){
    eind =( $(this).val() ); 
    console.log(eind);      
});
$('#aantalSloepen').change(function() {
aantal = ($(this).val());
console.log(aantal);
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "index.php",
      data: {
          date: begin,
          quantity: aantal
      },
      success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
          console.log(data);
      }
  });
});
});
```

Comment: Does the `exit;` in index.php stop the code?

Comment: _Small Point_ `if (isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['date'])) {` you should probably be testing `$_POST['quantity']` rather than testing `date` twice

Comment: What do you mean, `shows empty`? I can clearly see the output of the `var_dump()` in your console output.

Comment: I can see values of `date` and `quantity` from your console image

Comment: It also look like you are passing a TIME and not a DATE

Comment: All your test `echo`'s are getting in the way of what is getting send back to the javascript.

Comment: the var_dump() shows in my console but I want it to show in my php @jeroen

Comment: i think if php doesn't return a `json`. `echo`. and `return` are equivalent. 
So it cannot be faulted with string ! except other variable type

Comment: You misunderstand how an ajax call works: All output of your php script is stored in the `data` variable in the `success` function. So what you are seeing is really php's `print_r()`. Because it is an ajax call, the screen in your browser does not change, you will not see a blank screen with your php output like you perhaps expect.

Comment: so you are saying that I can never use the ajax data in php to make it use with file_get_contents function @jeroen

Comment: No, you can do anything you want like you would with a regular request but you'll have to check the results in the console.

Comment: How do I check the results in my console? do you have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First! There are duplicate conditions `isset($_POST['date'])`  (3 times) in your code:

```
 if (isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['date'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
            echo "Yes, mail is set";
            $value1 = $_POST['date'];
            $value2 = $_POST['quantity'];
        } else {
            echo "No, mail is not set";
        }
        exit;
    }
```

Second! You should remove `exit;` and try again!

Third: You should check your variable type, if your `$value1` and `$value2` is not a string, numeric. `echo` is false. try with `return`

**EDIT:**

Try this, it worked for me! the `.php` destination:

```
$value1 = "";
$value2 = "";
if (isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['quantity'])) {

        echo "Yes, mail is set";
        $value1 = $_POST['date'];
        $value2 = $_POST['quantity'];
    }
    else {
        echo "No, mail is not set";
}
echo $value1;
echo $value2;
```

The `ajax`:

[image]

The `result`

[image]

Comment: I removed `exit;` and changed the secods `isset($_POST['date'])` to quantity. but don't really understand what you mean by your third point.

Comment: @berto echo cannot be used with an object (example date time...) or array, you know? so i advise you to use `return` instead of `echo` :)

Comment: if `echo` in your `.php` is wrong, your ajax result will be nothing

Comment: you should use `var_dump()` to check your variables before return it !

Comment: I have changed the `print_r($_POST);` to `var_dump($_POST)` and it says array (size=0) empty

Comment: yeah, it means your post request is empty right from the start! let me see

Comment: Yes that was my question from the start why there is no data in it. I think my question wasn't really clear. But i want to use the data in a `file_get_contents` in PHP

Comment: if you have ultra viewer, i can help you directly

Comment: I don't have ultra viewer sorry.

Comment: @berto yeah, because your `.php` is not a `phpClass` it is only a `php` file, you used `echo` is **TRUE** !

Comment: @berto i've tried and it worked ! the key is people can't understand what you want exactly

Comment: the thing I want is if you change the value of a select ajax sends it to php where I can use it in file_get_contents

Comment: i do nothing with your script ! just fix your `.php`

Comment: @berto yeah you can see my result screenshoot

Answer (score 0):

Check the ContentType header in the AJAX request. It could be that it is being sent as JSON and PHP doesn't deserializer that into the $_POST array. It may need to be sent as serialized form data, like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php).

In my experience (albeit in .NET), if data isn't being picked out of the request by the server it's usually that the ContentType header isn't set correctly for how you're passing the data so the server doesn't understand how to pull it out.

**Edit:**
You can control this by setting `contentType` property in options object passed to `$.ajax`, the default is apparently `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` and when you pass an object to the `data` property, according to the `processData` property, the default behaviour is to serialize this into a query string, fitting the default contentType. Source: [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

So my mistake, looks like that should all be matching up, though I do usually like to be explicit with specifying these properties to avoid any confusion.

Comment: I think with his code ! It only send a Post request. doesn't it?

Comment: He's definitely sending a POST request, but the [ContentType header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) that goes along with it describes to the server how the data is being sent in that request (e.g. as JSON, form-encoded, etc.). You can control this by setting `contentType` in options object passed to [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), the default is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` which may not align with the raw object passed in the `data` property.

Comment: i think his variables is not string or numeric. it may be an object ! so echo false. xD

Comment: I set the contentType to the default 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' but it does not make a difference.